# Not able to install RVM

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to ruby programming and want to install RVM. I have followed steps provided in https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/, but i am not able to install it perfectly

During my installation i have followed steps as given below

```
STEP1 => user$ bash -s stable < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)

O/p
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0     19      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   120
100  796k  100  796k    0     0  64804      0  0:00:12  0:00:12 --:--:--  186k

Installing RVM to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/
installing - /usr/share/ruby-rvm/man/man1/rvm.1.gz -
installing - /usr/share/ruby-rvm/man/man1/rvm.1 -
RVM system user group 'rvm' exists, proceeding with installation.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /usr/share/ruby-rvm/ is complete.

# user,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne
```

Then i have fired "user$ rvm requirements"
It gives me output me like

```
Additional Dependencies:
# For Ruby / Ruby HEAD (MRI, Rubinius, & REE), install the following:
ruby: /usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion

# For JRuby, install the following:
jruby: /usr/bin/apt-get install curl g++ openjdk-6-jre-headless
jruby-head: /usr/bin/apt-get install ant openjdk-6-jdk

# For IronRuby, install the following:
ironruby: /usr/bin/apt-get install curl mono-2.0-devel
```

But when after installing these dependencies using apt-get it gives me error while firing command "user$ rvm list"

```
bash: /usr/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
```

and after that i am not able to access rvm.....
Please guide me for installing rvm with specific way
I am using ubuntu 11.10 beta

Comment: I have fired a command "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" and then go with "type rvm | head -1" and got the output like "rvm is a function". And after that i have run "rvm use 1.9.2 --default" and i got the version of ruby to 1.9.2.....

Comment: you are on right track...what do you need?

Answer (score 6):

fire a command `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`
and then go with
 `type rvm | head -1`
 and got the output like
 `rvm is a function`.

And after that i have run `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` and i got the version of ruby to 1.9.2

Comment: @Jeet If this is the answer to your question, please log in with your "Jeet" user and mark it as accepted. This prevents others coming here to solve a problem that's already been solved. Thanks